# Higher kinded Types and Type arguments for classes

Tags: class, haskell, higher-kinded-types

Suppose you are using the [`FlexibleInstances`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/FlexibleInstances) extension and have the `class`

```
class C a where
    f :: a b -> Maybe b
```

how would you implement it for a list of lists of a datatype. In particular, how would the type be written. The only thing I could find is how to do it for a single list, but not a list of lists or lists of any other datatypes.

This works:

```
instance C [] where
    ...
```

But this doesn't

```
data D = ...

instance C [[D]] where
    ...
```

How can I express something like this?

Comment: I think you might be looking for [`FlexibleContexts`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/FlexibleContexts), which allows this kind of expression.

Comment: On my phone now but you could make an alias `type A a = [[a]]` and allow instances for aliases

Comment: @jd823592 You can't do that: with an alias you can only declare instances for _fully applied_ aliases. E.g. `instance C (A a)` is ok, but `instance C A` is not.

Comment: @AJFarmar I took a look at those, but couldn't figure out how to apply them. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @BlankChisui In exactly the case described in the question. `FlexibleContexts` renders such instance declarations valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `newtype`

```
class C a where
    f :: a b -> b  -- the class before the OP edited

newtype LL a = LL [[a]]
instance C LL where
   f (LL xss) = ...
```

However, it is impossible to write a completely meaningful instance, since if the lists-of-lists is empty, it is impossible to extract an element. the best we could do is

```
instance C LL where
   f (LL xss) = case concat xss of
      (x:_) -> x
      _     -> error "f: no elements"
```

I'm not sure if that is a good idea.

---

As an alternative, you could use type families or functional dependencies. Here's a solution with type families.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class C a where
   type T a
   f :: a -> Maybe (T a)

instance C [[b]] where
   type T [[b]] = b
   f xss = case concat xss of
      []    -> Nothing
      (x:_) -> Just x
```

Comment: The result of the function will actually be something else but it will be depnding on b. I just wanted the signature to be small.

Also a new datatype is not an option.

Comment: What you seek is impossible in Haskell: you can have `instance C[], instance C [a], instance [[a]]` but no `instance C [[_]]` without a newtype wrapper. However, this might be an XY problem: why do you want to use such an instance and class? Won't `class C b a where f :: b -> a ; instance C [[a]] a`, with a suitable class `C`, be enough? Possibly with some fundep/type family inside to make the type `a` depend on `b` ?

Comment: That is actually how I have it implemented currently. The problem is it becomes awkward to use since `b` and `a` of `C` do not have a general connection. So when I have a function with signature `C b a => b a -> X a` I have to explicitly bind `a` and can not derive it from the first argument.

Comment: @BlankChisui That's what fundeps/type families are for. See the edit.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. Amazing how deep the type rabbit hole goes.